# Passing variable from one render template to another

Tags: python, flask

I have application which should have multiple render templates and some of them should keep variable.

Example of what I have now:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
    newTitle = request.form['title']
    newDescription = request.form['description']
    newLeftDesctiption = request.form['leftdescrib']
    return render_template('body.html', random = projectName,
                            title = newTitle,
                            desc = newDescription)
```

Here I'm passing attributes to template, now, what I would love to achieve is to pass those attributes to the new function, lets say called body with a different route, the function could take the attributes and pass them to template and then again pass them to another function with different route.

This way, lets say someone chooses projectname, then POST happends and we have another template showing project name, but also the function recognises that variable projectname is storing our "x", this means it can pass it further aswell.

Is this possible?

Comment: as Keeper says you can use the `session` for that. If you havent come across it this is an excellent tutorial that covers a huge amount of flask - https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins

Answer (score -1):

You should probably use [Session](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sessions.htm) for that:

```
from flask import Flask, session
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'any random string'

@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def index():
    # use session["newTitle"] if it exists
    if request.method == 'POST':
       session["newTitle"] = request.form['title']
       session["newDescription "]= request.form['description']
    ...

@app.route('/second_page/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def index():
    # use session["newTitle"] if it exists
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. I actualy know the use of session but though there might be other way.